# Log in without redirect using Ember Simple Auth

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

How would I go about logging a user in using ember simple auth without redirect them?

The authentication code looks like this:

```
session.authenticate(
  'authenticator:oauth2-password-grant',
  identification,
  password,
  ['read', 'write']
)
```

However, it redirects because of the config in my environment.js file:

```
ENV['ember-simple-auth'] = {
  authenticationRoute: 'login',
  routeAfterAuthentication: 'accounts.index',
  routeIfAlreadyAuthenticated: 'accounts.index'
};
```

Is there a parameter or something I can add to the authentication call to bypass this routerAfterAuthentication?

Answer (score 1):

In application route, override `sessionAuthenticated` method.

The transition to `routeAfterAuthentication` is done there, because you use `ApplicationRouteMixin`

```
//routes/application.js

...
sessionAuthenticated(){
  //do nothing or whatever
}
...
```